# Backbone returning my JSON but not getting the values

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

So my Backbone.js code is getting the JSON... I am trying to simply console out the models in the success callback of the fetch method but I just get back [r,r,r] instead of [object,object,object]. Pulling my hair out...

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend();
var PersonCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({    
    model : Person,
    url: 'js/names.json',
    parse: function(data) {
        console.log(data); // <--- this will return what I am looking for
        return data;
    }
});
var PersonView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        var self = this;
        self.collection = new PersonCollection();
        self.collection.fetch({success: function() {
            console.log(self.collection.models); // <-- how do I get it here?
        }});
    }                                     
});                               
var newView = new PersonView();
```

JSON

```
[
    { "name": "Linda", "birthYear": 1947},
    { "name": "Kat", "birthYear": 1977},
    { "name": "Jen", "birthYear": 1989}
]
```

edit: I want the same thing after the fetch I get when I console.log the data in a custom parse method in the collection. See comments in code above

Comment: I am seeing this issue using my exteranl JSON or I would have

Comment: use collection.set(json)

Comment: getting an error saying url is required...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting confused. The models in the collection are Backbone models which wrap *around* your records, not anything directly resembling your JSON you are giving to the collection. If you want that, consider `console.log(JSON.stringify(self.collection))`.

Comment: Let me clarify, I am not trying to get the JSON, I know that works. I am trying to pull it in and use it. I should be able to fetch the data in the collection and see it. that is what I am trying to do. Similar to this http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-collection/ but using an external JSON file

Comment: Slight confusion here, still. You just want to see what is in your collection after it has parsed the file requested, yes? If not, what exactly do you expect to see when you invoke `console.log(self.collection.models)`?

Comment: Yes, I want to see what is in my collection, not the JSON object I queried. I just updated my code above... in the parse method I am seeing an array of objects and I can call the paras on them. In the success callback I am getting an array of models but they do not include the data I expect. I am trying to step through the process of figuring out how to take the JSON and use the information... my end goal is to display on the page a list of names with ages

Comment: If you are messing with a custom method of parsing for your collection (as in http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/#Collection-parse), why haven't you placed that code where we can see what it does? Oh, I see, you added it.  Ok, so you want an array-of-objects representation of what your collection holds? That would be `collection.toJSON()`—yes, even though it says "toJSON", it's an object representation of the JSON, not a string of the JSON encoding, which was that `JSON.stringify` business gives you.

Comment: Generally, though, if you want to step through the models directly, you'd loop through the array of models and grab that model's `attributes` property for the current model's values.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Right now I am just trying to see how data gets from point A to point B.

Answer (score 0):

Looking [here](https://github.com/thomasdavis/backbonetutorials/blob/gh-pages/videos/beginner/index.html) suggests that your callback function will get passed the items, e.g.

```
users.fetch({
      success: function (users) {
        var template = _.template($('#user-list-template').html(), {users: users.models});
        that.$el.html(template);
      }
    })
```

So maybe a tweak to your callback will help...

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code, adding to toJSON now log the same object that parse function logged. If you are not getting same output there could be some thing wrong with other part of the code.

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend();
var PersonCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : Person,
    url: 'js/names.json',
    parse: function(data) {
        console.log(data); // <--- this return array of name objects
        return data;
    }
});
var PersonView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        var self = this;
        self.collection = new PersonCollection();
        self.collection.fetch({success: function() {
            console.log(self.collection.toJSON()); // <-- even this return array of name objects
        }});
    }
});
var newView = new PersonView();
```